# How to route between nested modules in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

So I have four modules as below:

```
|-app.module
    |-Home.module
       |-private.module
       |-public.module
```

AppModule lazy loads HomeModule and HomeModule Lazy Loads PrivateModule & PublicModule.

I have defined my routing for those modules as below:

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Home.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'private', loadChildren: './../private/private.module#PrivateModule'},
  { path: 'public', loadChildren: './../public/public.module#PublicModule' }
```

];

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

**private.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PrivateComponent } from './private/private.component';

export const privateRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '',component:PrivateComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(privateRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PrivateRoutingModule { }
```

`public.routing.ts` is same as `private.routing.ts`.

Now when I visit `localhost:4200` it loads Home Component Correctly. but when I try to visit `localhost:4200/private` or `localhost:4200/public` it reloads the browser & only loads privateComponent.

I have used two router-outlets. one inside app.component and another in home.component.

I want to load private component inside HomeModules RouterOutlet but it loads it in AppModules RouterOutlet.

Any Inputs?

Thanks.

Comment: Any example that we see, maybe plunker?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could define `private` and `public` routes as the `children` of your `homeModule`.

#### Home.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'private', loadChildren: './../private/private.module#PrivateModule'},
      { path: 'public', loadChildren: './../public/public.module#PublicModule' }
    ]
  }
]
```

then your private/public route configuration will be like

```
const publicRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PublicComponent
  }
]
```

Comment: I have updated the question details.Kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which part you did wrong, that's why I was asking for an example.

But [here one that works](http://embed.plnkr.co/i2cTMX/).

Good luck.